# How to call a class member function recursively from its own defintion in C++?

Tags: c++, function, class, c++11

I'm new to C++ and I need a class member function to call itself from its own definition, like this -

```
class MyClass {
public:  // or private: ?
    // Some code here
    // ...

    void myfunction();

    // ...
};

void MyClass::myfunction()
{
    // Some code here
    // ...

    // Call MyClass::myfunction() here, but how?    

    // ...
}
```

but I don't know the proper syntax for it and how can it be called by itself without creating an object usually done like this - `object_name.member_function()`, if possible?

And, will there be any difference if `myfunction()` belongs to `public:` or `private:`?

Comment: `myfunction()` is correct, if you are in the right scope. Just make sure your function definition of `myfunction()` is correct (i.e. it specifies a return type in both the declaration and definition).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the return type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the function isn't static, you already *do* have an instance to operate on

```
void MyClass::myfunction()
{
    // Some code here
    // ...

    this->myfunction();

    // ...
}
```

You could leave the `this->` off, I was just being more clear about how the function is able to be called.

Comment: `this->` is unnecessary here, no? Since the scope is implicit. Is there a reason not to recommend simply using `myfunction();`

Comment: @EyasSH Yes, as I mentioned it is unnecessary, I was using it to illustrate a point, that the function is being called off of the current instance of the object.

Answer (score 5):

`myfunction()` is in the scope of the class, so you can "simply" call it:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    // Some code here
    // ...

    void myfunction();

    // ...
};

void MyClass::myfunction()
{
    myfunction();
}
```

Note, however, that this will give a stack overflow. You need a means to stop the recursion.

Comment: Thanks. The function I'm using has a base condition to stop recursion, the code here is only for the purpose of understanding the question.

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't know the proper syntax for it and how can it be called by itself without creating an object usually done like this - `object_name.member_function()`, if possible?

Use:

```
void MyClass::myfunction()
{
    // Some code here
    // ...

    // Call MyClass::myfunction() here, but how?
    // One way to call the function again.
    this->myfunction();

    // ...
}
```

`this->mufunction()` can be replaced by `myfunction()`. Use of `this` is a stylistic option that makes the code easier to read for some, like me.

> And, will there be any difference if `myfunction()` belongs to `public:` or `private:`?

No, there won't be. You can call any member function of the class from another member function.

Comment: Thanks for that last line in your answer.

Comment: You can omit the explicit `this->` and just call it as `myfunction()` by itself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : Yes, I can. The answer by CoryKramer says so too.

Answer (score 1):

Member functions are actually a form of syntactic sugar. They describe a function that somehow secretly takes a pointer to an object instance which, inside the function, is accessible as `this`.

```
struct Foo {
    vod bar();
};

Foo foo;
foo.bar();
```

What you're really doing in the call here is calling a `Foo::bar(&foo);` and `bar` is really taking a pointer `Foo* this`. How that's done varies from implementation to implementation, some compilers/architectures will use a special register to track the current object.

An additional piece of syntactic sugar makes all member variables and functions visible to you within a member function as though they are locally scoped

```
struct Foo {
    int i;
    int add(int n) {
        return i + n;
    }
    int addx2(int n) {
        return add(n) * 2;
    }
};
```

What's actually happening here is:

```
return this->i + n;
```

and

```
return this->add(n) * 2;
```

This means its very easy to run into situations where you have conflicts between local and member names.

```
struct Foo {
    int i;
    Foo(int i) {
        i = i; // not what you expected
    }
};
```

For this reason, many engineers make careful use of case or prefixes or suffixes to help them distinguish members, parameters and variables.

```
struct Foo { // Uppercase for types and functions
    int m_i;  // m_ for member
    Foo(int i_, int j_) {
        int i = sqrt(i));
        m_i = i + j_;
    }
    int Add(int i) {
        return i_ + i;
    }
};
```

There are various different patterns people use - some people use `_name` to denote a member, some use `name_` and `fn_` to denote members.

```
struct Foo {
    int i_;
    int add_(int _i) {
        return i_ + _i;
    }
};
```

The main thing is to be consistent.